# Independent events in Probability theory(II)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Events A, B and C are independent, $\mathbb P(A)=0.1; \mathbb P(B)=0.6 ; \mathbb P(C)=0.9.$

1. Find the probability of an event $D=(A+B')(B+C')(C+A')$.
2. Find the probability of event D if it is known that event A has already occurred.

Consider the following Venn Diagram

[image]

According to the diagram:

$D=(0,1\cdot\ 0,4)+(0,6\cdot\ 0,1)+(0,9\cdot\ 0,9)-2(0,1\cdot\ 0,6\cdot\ 0,9)=0,802$

And for the second condition I also got the  wrong answer. Why?

Correct answer:

1. 0.0900.
2. 0.540.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working out  $D$ as a Boolean expression we find:

$$D=\left(A+B'\right)\left(B+C'\right)\left(C+A'\right)=\left(AB+AC'+B'C'\right)\left(C+A'\right)=ABC+A'B'C'$$
so that:
$$P\left(ABC+A'B'C'\right)=0.1\times0.6\times0.9+0.9\times0.4\times0.1=0.054+0.036=0.09$$
this because $ABC$ and $A'B'C'$ are mutually exclusive, $A,B,C$ are independent and (consequently) $A',B',C'$ are independent.

For the other question start with:

$P\left(D\mid A\right)=\frac{P\left(\left(ABC+A'B'C'\right)A\right)}{P\left(A\right)}=\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

The diagram is correct!

$$\mathbb{P}[D]=1-\mathbb{P}[A\cup B\cup C]+\mathbb{P}[ABC]$$

that means

$$1-(0.1+0.4+0.9-0.04-0.09-0.36+0.1\cdot0.4\cdot0.9)+0.1\cdot0.4\cdot0.9=0.09$$